# How to find out exact model of ATI video card you have?

Tags: amd-radeon

I'm trying to find out remotely what type of video card I have in order to get a fan for it, i'ts made by ATI (it's actually manufactured by ATI and not a third party company), the drivers only say Radeon HD 5700 series. I tried to compare clock speed but didn't find the correct one, and programs that detect (eg. Everest Ultimate) still only say 5700.

Is there a way to tell the exact model?

Answer (score 7):

[HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) will tell you the actual model number:

[image]

Comment: This only shows "R9 200 Series" for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably physically written on, or on a sticker, on the card, especially if it's that new.  This is the simplest way.  (You have to remove it to change the fan ANYWAY so...)

Comment: I'm not home and I'm logging in remotely, I was hoping to find out without going back and forth.

Comment: @Murtez - Oh! Well in that case, you might be out of luck - I think these cards report themselves generically to pretty much everything. :/  Hopefully somebody will know the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)? It should show you what you want.

[image]

Comment: That just says 5800 Series in the screenshot :D, I need the exact model, same problem I have.

Comment: @Murtez: It says not only *5800* but also lots of info like *GPU (Cypress), Technology (40nm), Die Size, Release Date, BIOS version, Device ID, etc.* Aren't these enough for you?

Comment: @Murtez - Well, you could take the detailed specs and use that to determine exactly the card you have, but it is a bit of legwork.

Comment: No, those won’t work; what Murtez wants is the *model number*, like what you see on the AIW9600 fan in [this shot](http://www.firingsquad.com/hardware/ati_all_in_wonder_9600xt/images/09.jpg).