# AMD Graphics card not showing its make and model

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a AMD Radeon graphics card in one of my computers. I tried to find out what model it is, and it only says that it is a AMD Radeon HD 7700 series.

I looked up documentation about AMD cards [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units), and discovered that there are 4 different cards in the HD 7700 series:

- HD 7730
- HD 7750
- HD 7770
- HD 7790.

I spent that the last 20 minutes trying to figure out just which of the 4 type is my graphics card. I tried `cpu-z`, `speccy` , `Device manager` and the `Catalyst Control Center`; but each time they only gave me the series number (7700 series), not the make and model.

Short of opening my computer, and looking at the print on the graphics card, how do I find out what type my graphics card is?

@Moderators - I know that I can't swear at other people here, but can I swear at AMD?

Comment: Do you have AMD drivers installed (Catalyst Control Center), which *should* (in any sane world) show you your card model?

Comment: @bertieb I checked the Catalyst Control Center. It does not say the model number there either, only that it is HD 7700 series, which is the same info as everywhere else :(

Comment: Wow, that's pretty poor from AMD! D: Might be worth adding that into your question so others don't ask the same thing :)

Comment: I thought I didn't have an AMD graphics card to make a useful screenshot, but it turns out I did :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How do I identify which of a series my AMD graphics card is?

AMD (neé ATI) seem to be a bit reticent to make the information readily available. However, they have a page on identifying which [model of graphics card you might have](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HowtoidentifythemodelofanATIgraphicscard.aspx):

Provided that the graphics drivers are correctly installed and functioning, the
model of the graphics card may be found using the AMD Catalyst™ Control Center.

#### Via Catalyst Control Center

You mentioned you tried looking in the Catalyst Control Centre, but there's a chance you overlooked this specific section:

> Open the AMD Catalyst™ Control Center by opening the Start menu and select Search.  In the Search box type "AMD Catalyst Control Center", then click on the AMD Catalyst Control Center icon.​​
>
> If the AMD Catalyst Control Center is in **Standard View** mode, then scroll down to Information, select Product Summary, then select Hardware.  The Graphics Chipset should indicate the model of the graphics card.​​​ If the AMD Catalyst Control Center is in **Advance View** mode, click on the Information tab located on the left side menu, then click Hardware.  The Graphics Chipset should indicate the model of the graphics card.​​

*([The AMD page has screenshots to illustrate this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HowtoidentifythemodelofanATIgraphicscard.aspx#CCC))*

#### Device Manager

You say that in `Device Manager` it only lists the *series* of the card. You may be able to find it out from the **Hardware ID**.

- Right click on `AMD Radeon HD 7700 series` and select `Properties`
- Select the `Details` tab
- Select `Hardware Ids` from the dropdown

See the following screenshot, which is from my <s>NVidia</s> Totally-an-AMD™ Graphics Card:

[image: AMD all the way, baby]

You can then use the **Device ID** (`DEV_XXXX`, where `XXXX` is device id) to look up on the [PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/). You can also identify the vendor this way.

The [same page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HowtoidentifythemodelofanATIgraphicscard.aspx#DID) on the AMD website goes through this process in a slightly different manner (using the `Windows System Information Tool` instead).

#### Physical Inspection

[AMD suggest this as a viable alternative](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HowtoidentifythemodelofanATIgraphicscard.aspx#Physical)<sup>1</sup>.

#### More Tools

**Note**: I am hesitant to mark this question as a duplicate- with the tools you've tried these may not give any more useful information.

But for the sake of completeness: `HWMonitor` (as mentioned by Gesicht in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/306905/461558)) or `GPU-Z` (as mentioned by Mehper C. Palavuzlar in [another answer to the same question](https://superuser.com/a/235215/461558)) *might* be worth trying.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>: You may commence your swearing. I suggest calling them *"fusking cloff prunkers"*, and go from there.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Catalyst Control Center you should be able to see if the card is crossfire capable.  If it is, it's a 50 or 70.  If not, it is a 30 or a 90.  That get's you half way.  The 50 or 70 are the one's you want because they normally have a gig of DDR5 instead of DDR3 memory.  DDR5 is faster, and as always in the graphics arena, faster is better.